# Extension of mod $\ell$-adic cyclotomic character and trivial character

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

(Sorry for my poor english..)

Let $\ell$ be a prime and $\mathbb{F}_{\ell}$ be a finite field with $\ell$ elements. Let $\chi_{\ell}$ be a mod $\ell$-adic cyclotomic character, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\chi_{\ell} : Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\to \mathbb{F}_{\ell}^{*}.
\end{equation} 
Consider a two-dimensional Galois representation $\rho$ such that
\begin{equation}
\rho : Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\to GL_2(\mathbb{F}_{\ell})
\end{equation}
with unramified at $\ell$ and 
$$ \rho =\begin{bmatrix} \chi_{\ell} & *\\
0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}.$$
How many $\rho$ are there? (It means that how many $*$ satisfying above condition?)

Comment: Please clarify your question given that it might be rephrased like this :  given a degree $m=order(\chi)$ cyclic extension $K/\Bbb{Q}$ and a prime $\ell\equiv 1\bmod m$, is there a degree $\ell$ cyclic extension $E/K$ such that $E/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois and $G=Gal(E/\Bbb{Q})= \{{\scriptstyle\pmatrix{a^{(\ell-1)/m}&b\\0&1}},a\in \Bbb{F}_\ell^*,b\in \Bbb{F}_\ell\}$ ? If there is such a $E$ then there are $\ell$ homomorphisms $G\to G$ sending ${\scriptstyle\pmatrix{a^{(\ell-1)/m}&0\\0&1}}$ to itself.

Comment: @reuns Thanks!!

Comment: As written, there are no such extensions! Since $\chi_\ell$ is ramified at $\ell$, $\rho$ must be too! Did you mean unramified outside $\ell$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 It's my mistake. $\rho$ is unramified outside $\ell$.

Comment: Did you mean $\chi_\ell$ is a character of $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_\ell)/\Bbb{Q})$...